# Accidentally deleted history in Safari. Is there any way to get it back?

Tags: safari, history

I accidentally clicked the delete button when my mouse had clicked on 5 September 2015 under the history page.

Is it stored somewhere temporarily or something before it is deleted?

Comment: The information you're looking for might be in your router's logs. Try checking those.

Comment: Have you tried search engine history of whatever search engine you use? (Google, bing, etc, they usually all save your search history).  It's not browser history, but it is at least a breadcrumb.

Comment: The history may remain in other connected iOS device. Turn off Wi-Fi and cellular network to avoid syncing and check the history record.

Comment: This almost feels like a trick to get an answer to "Ok so I deleted the history of the porn - is there anyway my wife will find out?"

Answer (score 5):

No, once you delete history, it is removed from the database.

That database is backed up, so you can use your backup method (Time Machine backup, etc) to restore the following files:

```
~/Library/Safari/History*
```

Comment: The last backup was yesterday, so It's not gonna do anything.

Comment: But whatever, that sucks. Had visited some really important sites.

Comment: The last backup will indeed be at least somewhat useful, as long as you had any useful browsing history before "yesterday".  You just lose any history between "yesterday" and "now".

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 I said in my post that I had clicked on "5 September 2015" and clicked delete. That only deletes history from 5th September 2015.